# Add class to parent div based on content of certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

I have the following html and I want to add class in the parent div class which is class="boxgrid", depending on the teaser_title...

```
<div class="boxgrid">
     <img src="my_image1.jpg" alt="Image 1"> 
     <div class="cover boxcaption"> 
          <div class="teaser-title">Image 1</div> 
     </div> 
</div>

<div class="boxgrid">
     <img src="my_image2.jpg" alt="Image 2"> 
     <div class="cover boxcaption"> 
          <div class="teaser-title">Image 2</div> 
     </div> 
</div>
```

Now, I tried this code...

```
$('.teaser-text').each(function() { 
      var teasertext = $('.teaser-text').text().replace(/ /g,"_").toLowerCase(); 
      $('.boxgrid').addClass(teasertext); 
});
```

The above code outputs as follows.

```
<div class="boxgrid **image_1image_2**">
     <img src="my_image1.jpg" alt="Image 1"> 
     <div class="cover boxcaption"> 
          <div class="teaser-title">Image 1</div> 
     </div> 
</div>
```

what did I do wrong? anyone willing to help me with this little problem. Thanks..

Comment: There is no div with class `teaser-text` in your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(this)`

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.teaser-text').each(function() { 
      var teasertext = $(this).text().replace(/ /g,"_").toLowerCase(); 
      $(this).closest('.boxgrid').addClass(teasertext); 
});
```

Comment: sorry.. it should be class='teaser-title'..

anyways, it solved my problem.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding class to element with '.boxgrid' class name.
So each time it will find first div with class 'boxgrid'.

Instead of `$('.boxgrid').addClass(teasertext);`

Use this,

```
$(this).closest('.boxgrid').addClass(teasertext);
```

This will find closest element with class name 'boxgrid'.